# Header Location на php срабатывает только со второго раза

Tags: php

При использовании такой конструкции:

```
if($_GET['exit']) {
     @session_destroy(); 
     unset($_GET['exit']);
     mysql_close($link);   
     @Header("Location: /registration/index.php");
}
```

Переадресация на нужную страницу происходит только после второго нажатия на ссылку. Возможно это от того, что предыдущие операции не успевают выполниться? Подскажите, пожалуйста, как этого избежать?

Comment: Так не бывает..

Comment: И не забывайте, что header'ы отправляются тогда и только тогда, когда ещё не было никакого вывода со страницы. Даже битового префикса от файла в ЮТФ-8. Надеюсь вы это учитываете.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

сделай так

```
 if(isset($_GET['exit'])) { // добавь isset
    session_destroy(); 
 unset($_GET['exit']); 
Header("Location: /registration/index.php");
```

}

И посмотри ошибки, если таковые есть.

такая проверка

```
if($_GET['exit']) {
```

Звучит примерно так, если exit но должен он быть чему-то равен, чтобы сравнивать, иначе вызывать для проверки параметра нужно [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) которая проверяет параметр на NULL что собственно тебе и нужно